# Lookahead regular expression

Tags: regex, boost

I am looking to match the following pattern

(1)

**10digits sometext** (e.g. 1235873490   ABCD EFGK)

In a text that might have the pattern above, as well as very similar pattern like this one

(2)

**10digits sometext decimal_number** (e.g. 9835873490   VBGF XMF  23.233)

How I can write the regular expression to match only pattern (1) and ignore pattern (2)?

I have looked at negative lookaheads using something like this:

```
(\d{10})\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+))\s*(?!(\d+.\d+))
```

but cannot get it to work. Any ideas? By the way, I am using c++ boost::regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start with the straightforward version:

```
(\d{10}         # 10 digits
    (?:\s+\w+)+)  # some text, separated by spaces,
                  # at least one time
(?!\s*\d+\.\d+) # not followed by a decimal number
```

I changed your `[A-Za-z0-9]` to `\w` for simplicity, and allowed it to occur as many times as it wants.

However, this will also match the second string - it will gobble up the `23` at the end, then see that this doesn't have a decimal number following (it's followed by ".23"), so it will match.

To prevent this, we can say that it must be followed by a space or the end of the text:

```
(\d{10}(?:\s+\w+)+)
    (?=\s|$)      # it must be followed by a space or end of text
(?!\s*\d+\.\d+)
```

However, this still has a problem. Now, it will match up to "...XMF", but then see it is followed by a decimal number, and backtrack. It will go back to "...VBGF" and then match, since "VBGF" isn't followed by a decimal.

To prevent this, we can tell the regex that it can't backtrack once it has matched our main section:

```
(?> # added '?>': not allowed to backtrack once this group is matched
    \d{10}(?:\s+\w+)+)      
(?=\s|$)(?!\s*\d+\.\d+)
```

Alternately, if you know that there will always be 2 parts in **sometext**, this will also solve the backtracking:

```
 (\d{10}(?:\s+\w+){2}  # can only occur twice
     )    
 (?=\s|$)(?!\s*\d+\.\d+)
```